# Could not connect from linux container(docker-desktop) to service on localhost windows

Tags: docker

How to Connect to Host service on windows from within a Docker Container on Docker Desktop WINDOWS?

The service is running locally on localhost:9092

I tried using `host.docker.internal` but doesn't seems to work.

I tried this example from Docker-desktop document

https://docs.docker.com/desktop/windows/networking/#per-container-ip-addressing-is-not-possible

Run the following command to start a simple HTTP server on port 8000.

```
python -m http.server 8000
```

If you have installed Python 2.x, run `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000`.
Now, run a container, install curl, and try to connect to the host using the following commands:

```
docker run --rm -it alpine sh
apk add curl
curl http://host.docker.internal:8000
exit
```

The above doesn't seem to work on windows.

Comment: *doesn't seem to work on windows* : Could you add the error message you get, please ?

Answer (score 0):

You should not start the service binded to localhost (127.0.0.1). Start the service binded to the IP of docker for desktop (192.168.x.x usually). Otherwise, start the service attached to all interfaces using 0.0.0.0, this could be insecure though.